# how to reverse arraylist<Double> of extracted column data in file

Tags: java, file, csv, arraylist, filereader

I am working with csv file having very large dataset. while reading file i had extracted 4th place(BALANCE) ';' separated numeric value from each rows  through while loop iteration. and make a arraylist of Double after some mathematical calculation(here division).

Now I want to store this arraylist of Double in reverse order(from end to beginning).as its original position(here 4th  place in the file).example

```
 input

            1,2,3,4
            2,3,4,5
            3,4,5,6
 output
            1,2,3,6
            2,3,4,5
            3,4,5,4
```

I had try to reverse it but not succeeded. I don’t  know whether it was suitable method for my problem or not. How can I do this?

Then after using string builder I write back data in new file using writer method.

```
package csvtest7;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Csvtest7 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        String filename = "sample dataset.csv";
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("lyupdated.csv"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        try {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            inputStream.next();
            int count = 0;
            int number = 11;
            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String data = inputStream.next();
                String[] values = data.split(",");
                double balance = Double.parseDouble(values[3]);    
                balance = balance / number;
                count = count+1;
                values[3] = String.valueOf(balance);
                list.add(balance);
                Collections.reverse(list);  // I tryied this method but don't work.
                // iterate through the values and build a string out of them
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                //  String newData = sb.toString();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(values[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                        sb.append(";");
                    }
                }
                // get the new string
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                writer.write(sb.toString()+"\n");
            }
            writer.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Csvtest7.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the Output of your code?

Comment: You're reversing and printing the list at each iteration, every time you add a new element to the list. Surely that's not what you want. What you want is to fill the list using a loo, and THEN reverse it and print it. For your own brain sanity and ours, please indent your code properly

Comment: my code output is simple like as shown in example.perticuler extracted column should be printed in reverse order after updation(here i update with divition).

Comment: You have posted this before. Why don't you try and follow the advice given there and, again, here? Read the file while collecting the (modified) values of the fourth field in a list. Reverse the list. Read the file again, replace the fourth field with the next value from the list and write the reassembled line to the output file.